# how to extract input type = hidden in jmeter using regularexpression extractor or cssextractor or xpath extractor

Tags: jmeter

I want to get the value of
input type = "hidden" name = "CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN"
value="dfsdgdg"

below is the response that I am getting for my first request. I want to read the value from the first request and use it in my subsequent request. I tried using a regular expression extractor,
CSS selector extractor and XPath extractor none of them worked[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXuZF.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXm8q.png)
input type="hidden" name="CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN" value="4edwUQQn9gYbf5zYjz4fuRIfyu3lzoXi3_27IU7Jj54RLskSWvVvnKadSTdGYpVofQmqn79hT9dHLYeBsZf0h6-M9HErsMb6eXiHWTXHXt4="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp): `//input[@type='hidden' and @name='CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN']/@value`

   [image]

   However it's better to go for [XPath2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations) (the same syntax can be used)

   [image]
2. [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp): `input[type=hidden][name=CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN]`

   [image]

Comment: I am using Xpath extractor in test plan and debug sampler to view the result when I see the result in debug sampler its printing me empty string no token is present

Comment: I have a complex dom and it is printing empty string debug sampler

Comment: this is  url that is giving me craft_csrf_token  https://snapmed.no/kontakt-1    when you click on send I want to correlate the craft_csrf_token and post the response. I was not able to do it with regularexpression extractor, XPath extractor or csss extractor can help me in this?

Comment: You have been given all the help needed (if not more), here is the [evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNMim.gif) that the extraction works using instructions provided above. What else do you want? Check out [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) if anything remains unclear

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor), [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor) and [CSS Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) as in the other answer. They all work well if your response is a valid HTML.

Here is another option with a [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

[image]

Regular expression

```
name="CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN" value="(.*?)"
```

**Note**: You can validate the syntax of regular expressions, CSS, XPath, etc in the [View Result Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree).

Comment: I am seeing CSRF_TOKEN value as empty string do not know exact reason I think because it has complex DOM in the response

Comment: Can you please check the responses inside the View Results tree? Also, set the Apply to --> Main sample and sub-samples and check if it works. Are you getting the token in the response body or in the header?

Comment: yes, I set it main sample and sub-samples only. I am getting it in the response body. My response body is complex it has 1000 lines. the craft_csrf_token is at 450 line. moreover it even has <script> tag in it

Comment: You can check the XPath, CSS, and regular expressions in the View Result tree. Select the response and verify the expression. Also, you can share the response  to check it further.

Comment: The response is too long this is the API I am hitting https://snapmed.no/kontakt-1 I am getting csrf token in the above API  response. Yes I am checking the results in view result tree using debug sampler